# implies_id and users in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-13

what is the usage of these field in xml odoo?

```
<field name="category_id" ref="employee_document.module_category_employee_document"/>
<field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_creat_employee_document_order'))]"/>
<field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root')), (4, ref('base.user_admin'))]"/>
```

I had a button not appears even the group privilige is given, I tried to add <implies_id> and it worked after that and the button shown, I didn't understand why and what those fields represents

Comment: implied_ids is simply inheriting the rights of that group.
In your case, group_creat_employee_document_order must have proper rights to view that button.
From the front end, go to menu groups, search your group, and check the inherited page you will see this group there, and your new group will inherit all its rights.
You will need to activate the Developer's mode to check this from the front end

Comment: Could you please add more of your XML here? It's always good to at least have the `record` tag around everything, because there you will see the model of that record. I know that this relates to `res.groups` but others wanting to answer and help probably not. And you're writing about a button. Add the XML (or better a simplified snippet) of the view with the button. Thanks

Comment: ``Implied groups`` is an extension of ``res.groups`` and ``res.users`` with a relation for ``implied`` or ``inherited`` groups.  Once a user belongs to a group, it automatically belongs to the implied groups (transitively).